# Is it inefficient to initialize a variable multiple times rather than reassigning one?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app where I have to loop over an array of objects and for each one I'm calling a helper function.

In that helper function I need to pass a variable to **another** helper function.

My question is, is it bad practice to initialize that variable in the first helper function every time?

Basically:

Example 1: Initialize b in funcA

```
funcA(byte[] bytes) {
    ...
    byte b = bytes[0];
    funcB(b);
}

while(...) {
    byte[] bytes;
    funcA(bytes);
}
```

OR

Example 2: Initialize b outside and just reassign

```
byte b;

funcA(byte[] bytes) {
    ...
    b = bytes[0];
    funcB(b);
}

while(...) {
    byte[] bytes;
    funcA(bytes);
}
```

Which is better? (I'm calling funcA approx 20-30 times) I suppose I could just do `funcB(bytes[0])` but I want to assign it to a variable for readability.

Comment: A function should return a new value and leave the old value alone.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice *not* to initialize that variable in the helper function every time.

In general, variables should be defined in the narrowest scope possible.  It is more efficient to have variables defined only where they're used and not keep variables around when they're not used.  "Creating the new variable here" is basically free; it just becomes part of the memory allocated on the stack for this function.

Comment: Huh, why did I not think of that, that makes sense.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Performance concerns should almost never drive your system design. First make sure that your code makes sense from logical point of view and implement it accordingly and then measure actual execution time, memory usage, etc.

In your case that array should be defined and initialized where it's needed. I'm assuming you are passing some values in it, so it makes total sense to have it declared in `while` and passed further to `funcA`. If you are going to pass empty uninitialized object to your function there is a great chance that you are doing something very wrong, and there is actually no need to pass that object at all.

Comment: Oh for sure I'm assigning bytes to something first, I just stripped down my code completely for this question.

Comment: Then for `byte` your third option is the best one, simply pass it `in place`, there is no need to create variable to use it once as a function argument. In fact it is the opposite of readability. Anonymous variables are awesome and more importantly they are clear about where they are being used. Declaring any variable at `global` scope is generally bad, since you can't know where they are being used without tracking them by hand.